# Code not working on different php version

Tags: php

i have problems with part of my code. In my local machine this code works, i have php7

```
$totals = array_values(
    array_count_values(
        array_map(function($x)
        {
            return explode('-', $x)[0];
        }, $arraySKU2)
    )
);
```

This is the error that i get on server that have php version 5.3.3.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

I tried to find solution on internet, but i didnt make it.
Can someone help me please, i dont know how to write changes?

Comment: Would help to tell us what version is on the machine that's not working.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: 5... what? 5.6? 5.5? 5.4? 5.3? 5.2? 5.1? etc.

Comment: 5.3.3. version..

Comment: all 4 functions which you are using having support till 4.0 to 7,

Comment: Ouch. 5.3.3 went end of life nearly _5_ years ago. You can't really go on using 7 on your dev machine if you're having to deploy on this antiquated version. Can I suggest you find better hosting?

Comment: remove this line and run your code on your server, check if it make sense to debug

Comment: @devpro Not sure array access on function returns are though?

Comment: @JonStirling that is not my decission, i must use that version on server...

Comment: which line @devpro

Comment: one more idea, create a sub domain, and upgrade php version on sub domain and try.

Comment: @dokica  *which line* ---> code which you shared in your question.

Comment: I cant remove that line, i needed it thorugh my all code

Comment: just for debugging purpose. ok try sub domain idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working:

```
 return explode('-', $x)[0];
```

Try assiging the result of `explode` to a variable and access the first element from that variable.

According to the [release notes for PHP 5.4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), accessing data this way has not been possible in versions older than 5.4.0

Finally, your code could look like this:

```
$totals = array_values(array_count_values(array_map(function ($x) {
    $explodedValues = explode('-', $x);
    return $explodedValues[0];
}, $arraySKU2)));
```

Comment: I agree, though I don't think it would cause the error provided, though I guess that could be anywhere.

Comment: How i can do that?

Comment: Yes error is in this part [0]

Comment: @dokica I've added the proper code for that

Comment: Thanks, its working!

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only. If you want to point out their mistake, just post a comment. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.